# Alpha Shapes in pgRouting

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, routing

I am attempting to follow Anita Grazer's post on creating alpha shapes in pgRouting.

My query:

```
CREATE TABLE home_isodist (id serial, max_cost double precision);
SELECT addgeometrycolumn('home_isodist','geom',4326,'POLYGON',2);

INSERT INTO home_isodist (max_cost, geom) (
SELECT 1.5, ST_SetSRID(geom_way,4326)
FROM 
pgr_alphashape('SELECT id, ST_X(geom_way) AS x, ST_Y(geom_way) AS y FROM home_catchment5km WHERE cost < 1.5'));
```

I am getting the following error code:

```
ERROR:  column "geom_way" does not exist
LINE 5: SELECT 1.5, ST_SetSRID(geom_way,4326)
```

Comment: Does the table home_catchment5km have a column called geom_way? If not, that will be your problem.

Comment: yes It does.. :(

Answer (score 2):

The result of

```
pgr_alphashape('SELECT id, ST_X(geom_way) AS x, ST_Y(geom_way) AS y 
FROM home_catchment5km WHERE cost < 1.5')
```

does not contain a column called "geom_way". That explains the error you get.

Please see the pgRouting docs for details:

[pgr_alphashape](http://docs.pgrouting.org/v2.0.0-alpha/src/driving_distance/doc/dd_alphashape.html#pgr-alphashape) Returns a table with (x, y) rows that describe the vertices of an alpha shape.

You want:

[pgr_pointsAsPolygon](http://docs.pgrouting.org/v2.0.0-alpha/src/driving_distance/doc/dd_points_as_polygon.html#pgr-points-as-polygon) Returns the alpha shape as polygon geometry.

Comment: I changed the function name but its not working